# Why JNLP (Java Web Start) does not download jar file?

Tags: java, java-web-start, jnlp

Why Java Web Start does not download Jar files which specified in resources?

I'm using jdk 1.5 to build my application. There is good reasons to use jdk 1.5 so that I can not upgrade it.

Jdk demo and samples used a servlet to specify location of JNLP and security checking. If I use this servlet, jnlp does not work and its jar files does not download while if write address of jnlp directly in codebase attribute by prefixing file:/localhost/ it works!

Comment: Be sure to check the JNLP (made by the servlet) using JaNeLA, available at my [share drive](https://drive.google.com/drive/#folders/0B5B9wDXIGw9lUnJaUjA2cmlVRE0).

Comment: I think I found the problem! I was in an exploaded artifact environment which was a location other than actual tomcat/webapps/ROOT so that addresses in jnlp don't match to where they should point to. If I package all JWS in a war file and deploy it manually it works fine.

Comment: *"I think I found the problem! ... If I package all JWS in a war file and deploy it manually it works fine"*  Glad you sorted it!  :)  For the benefit of others who may encounter the same problem, it would be really helpful if you could write up an answer for your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I found the problem! I was in an exploaded artifact environment which was a location other than actual tomcat/webapps/ROOT so that addresses in jnlp don't match to where they should point to. If I package all JWS in a war file and deploy it manually it works fine.